# Not closing quartz scheduler connection after wrapping it in aspect

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, connection-pooling, aspect

I have problem with my aspect process. I have scheduled quartz job witch I wrapped in aspect. When I do it without aspect I don't have problems , but when I wrap it in aspect after process is executed several times an application seems to be in a hang state while trying to connect to database. The logs show several J2CA0045E errors due to ConnectionWaitTimeoutExceptions as well as other errors referring to problems with obtaining free connections from the pool. When I look for my free connections there are none available. It seems like my aspect is not closing connections. I don't understand why is this happening because when I don't use aspect everything is doing well and connections are closed.

My aspect configuration in applicationContext.xml is like this :

```
<!-- Aspect -->
<bean id="logAspect" class="hr.kket.cscada.web.util.aspect.LoggingAspect" />
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
    <aop:aspect id="aspectLoggging" ref="logAspect" >
        <aop:pointcut id="syncUdwAspect"
        expression="execution(* hr.kket.cscada.services.balancing.BalancingService.syncAllUdwForGasDay(..))" />
        <!-- @Around -->
        <aop:around method="logProcess" pointcut-ref="syncUdwAspect" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

My loggingAspect class is like this :

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
    public Object logProcess(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        <!-- some code before -->
    int br = dbparameter;//

    if(br == 0) {
        log.error('some message');
    } else {
        insertSomethingInDB();//inside I open and close connection, this works well.
        try {
            Object result = joinPoint.proceed();// connection of this job is not closing with aspect
            <!-- some code after -->
            insertSomethingInDB();//inside I open and close connection, this works well.
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info(e.getMessage());
            <!-- some code here -->     
            throw e;
        }   
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be sure I understood it: your aspect method is using the same connection management that the rest of the application, isn't it?

Comment: yes. it is using the same conn.

Comment: Can you post more configuration and source code from this project? (datasource setup, transactional setup if any and, of course, your BalancingService class)

Comment: I figured it out. There was problem with closing connections. They were not closed correctly in one part of balancing service. Thank you for your reply!